# Extract all sequences from a string

Tags: excel, vba

I have this string "ABXBBBBSS" in A1.

I need to get this result displayed in the rows below the cell where the string is, starting from the longest sequence:
B = 4
S = 2
A = 1
X = 1

In other words, I need a code that searches for sequences of very character in a certain string, but the alphanumerical text in that string is completely variable.

If a character appears in more than one sequence, I just need to know the longest sequence.

The string could be "ERE222", "1", "IT64WWW", etc.

For "ERE222", I'd want this:
2 = 3
E = 1
R = 1

Answer (score 1):

For fun, if one has Excel O365 you could try a formula instead of VBA using some nested `LET()`:

[image]

Formula in `A2`:

```
=LET(A,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&CONCAT(LET(X,MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1),Y,IFERROR(IF(X<>MID(A1&"|",SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)-1,,2),1),X&"</s><s>",X),X),Y))&"</s></t>","//s"),B,LEFT(A,1),C,LEN(A),D,SORT(TRANSPOSE(CHOOSE({1;2},TRANSPOSE(B),TRANSPOSE(C))),2,-1),E,UNIQUE(INDEX(D,0,1)),E&"="&INDEX(D,MATCH(E,INDEX(D,0,1),0),2))
```

Took me a while, and maybe it can be done with a better formula =)

GL

Comment: Hi GL and thank you for your time! Unfortunately I use Excel 2019, which doesn't have the LET formula.

Comment: @Dolphin975 then I recommend you start working on some VBA code=)